# open file attachments(pdf,xls,txt,doc,etc) in html(or htm) without downloading

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, attachment

I have an application in which on a certain page user has the facility to upload a file(pdf,doc,xls,txt,etc). When user go again on that page and click on that attachment, it downloads and then opens it.

**Now, user want to open that attachment directly without downloading. Attachment should be opened in htm/html format in web browser window in new tab.**

This application is in java(jsp/servlets).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: So... you're basically asking how to convert a file of arbitrary type to HTML? You might want to redirect your user to Google Docs.

Comment: I think I dont want to convert the attached file. I just want to open that attachment in my application w/out downloading.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the caching type/method to the response of the first time the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ZOHO Remote API](https://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Remote-API-Reference.html) to view documents online, if they're accessible at a public HTTP address, for example: https://viewer.zoho.com/api/urlview.do?url=http://elsa.berkeley.edu/~saez/TabFig2005prel.xls